# How to succeed in remote TCS research as undergraduate

Tags: soft-question, research-practice

I am participating in a remote summer research program in theoretical computer science due to the current pandemic. I recognize that given the current situation, it may be harder to collaborate with my advisor. Additionally, another benefit of these programs is the social interactions with other undergraduates doing similar research, but this will clearly be hard to recreate, if at all.

Given these limitations, what advice do you have to be successful during the summer research program? Anything from work habits to preparations and tools for weekly meetings would be helpful. Any other tips or advice would be very helpful, too.